# set interval for QR coder scanner in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, qr-code

I need to scan the same barcode for many times . I'm using qr_code_scanner plugin for scanning. problem is it scans continuously without any gap .so when i scanned two times , it takes as 5 or 6 times like that. I need to set interval . Any help might help . Thanks .

```
'''updateQRView(QRViewController controller) {
    qrController = controller;

    qrController?.scannedDataStream?.listen((data) {
      validateBulkReceive(data.code.toString());
      Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      });
      
    }
    );
  }'''
```

'''Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {

```
ScanPackageBloc _scanPackageBloc =
ScanPackageBlocProvider.getScanPackageBloc(context);
SnackbarUtil snackbarUtil = SnackbarUtil();
snackbarUtil.buildContextItemScan = context;

//var scanArea = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 400 ||
//        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 400) ? 250.0 : 300.0;
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
  child: QRView(
    key: qrKey,
    onQRViewCreated: _scanPackageBloc.updateQRView,
    overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(cutOutBottomOffset: 0,
        borderColor: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderLength: 30,
        borderWidth: 5,
        cutOutSize: 250),
  ),
);
```

}'''

Answer (score 1):

This code will check if the last scan was performed less than the specified duration, if the duration exceeds it will print the data

```dart
DateTime? lastScan;
...
_qRViewController?.scannedDataStream.listen((data) {
  final currentScan = DateTime.now();
  if (lastScan == null || currentScan.difference(lastScan!) > const Duration(seconds: 1)) {
    lastScan = currentScan;
    print(data.code);
  }
});
```